# Simple AJAX search form

Tags: search, ajax, jquery

So I've been following the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/search-form) on how to create a search form in Craft and it works fine. But instead of having a results.twig page I would like to have just one index page and get all the results with AJAX. Is there a simple way to accomplish this in Craft? And if so, does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own search...
lets say this is your html

```
<input type="input" id="searchTags" placeholder="Search">
<input type="button" id="startSearch" value="Go">
<div id="results"></div>
```

then you have the following script:

```
$("#startSearch").click(function(){
    var data = {
        action: 'pluginhandle/controller/searchEntries',
        options: $("#searchTags").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: '/',
       data: data,
       success: function(response){
       // replace content from $("#results") with your new html
       },
    ....
   });
});
```

Your controller would look like

```
public function actionSearchEntry(){ 
     $criteria = new ElementCriteriaModel(ElementType::Entry);     
     // build your criteriaModel based on your needs
     $html = $this->renderTemplate('results.twig', array(
         'entries' => $criteria->find()
     ));
     return $this->returnJson($html);
}
```

your results.twig would be like

```
{% if entries is defined and entries|length %}
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li>
                {{ entry.title }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi Brad! Thanks for the reply. So I need to create my own plugin to accomplish this?

Comment: The answer was mine - Brad just edited it because I messed up formatting.
I`m not sure if there is a craft build in way to accomplish it. Maybe there is and Brad could tell us - but I never used it. You are more flexible if you create your own plugin. All in all I made about 20 pages different pages with craft and none of them without a custom plugin. It is really easy, fast and you have more control.

Comment: Hi @Robin Schambach, I'm trying to set up the code in your example. I made a plugin via pluginfactory.io (I've never made a Craft plugin before) and I made the controller just like this example. The JS code gives me an error (Requested page not found. [404]). My JS file is in the public folder and my results.twig page is at the root in my templates folder. Could you please help me out? I would really like this to work

Comment: could you please come here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74190/plugin-developement it can have 1000 reasons so it's better to chat in the room